# SSL not running right on Virtuemart?

Tags: ssl, joomla, virtuemart

I have gone other the whole page from my shop and changes all requests to https.

However it still shows the red cross on chrome? It works sometimes and then if you navigate away it goes red. How can i go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your page contains both secure and non secure content. If you use SSL pathes to  all your content(css-files, js-files, images, all links) should start with `https` or pathes should be relative.

For exalmple:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />` - secure

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site.com/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />` - secure

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://site.com/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />` - non secure

I think this is the problem. I hope it will help.